# Binding style to expression calculated from ngFor loop

Tags: angular

Let's say I have function that calculates colour from black to white based on sum of height of bunch of divs created with ngFor loop from random data.

I need to calculate it and bind those divs background colour to this value. To be able to calculate all their heights I'd need to calculate colour in ngAfterViewChecked() and store it in variable. But binding it to style would obviously cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

Is there any elegant solution to such cause, or some walkaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<div [style.background-color]="yourProperty">
```

And Start your property with an initial background color you like. And update as you wish later.

Comment: I think you did not read my question carefully. I'm not asking how to bind variable to style. My problem is dealing with component lifecycle and calculating variable after change detection (because all data and divs are being replaced) but still updating style after that.